# iconv(1) inconv(3) giving different conversions - Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Tags: c++, iconv

The following

`u8"abc ß α € àḃç Málaga uña"`

Is being converted on the command line by

`echo abc ß α € àḃç Málaga uña| iconv --verbose -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT`

to

`"abc ss ? EUR abc Malaga una"`

However, in my 64 bit C++ programme (gcc 6.3.0), using `iconv_open(u8"US-ASCII//TRANSLIT", u8"UTF-8")`, it is being converted to

`"abc ss ? EUR ??? M?laga u?a"`

`iconv(3)` doesn't return -1.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Here's some help: how to post a [mcve] on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm guessing that you are passing the input string wrongly in the C++ program, so that when `iconv()` sees the characters they are already wrong. But you should post that code to be sure. I mean, you show us the full script that works fine, but only onne line of the one that fails...

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation (your code is easy enough to reproduce, but you should have posted it), the solution is to call, at the beginning of your `main()`:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");  //#include <locale.h> of course
```

Why is this needed? Well, arguably transliteration rules may depend on the language used (that will be your `LANG` environment variables), so you have to apply that by calling `setlocale()`.

Knowing that, it is easy to reproduce your issue in the command line:

```
echo abc ß α € àḃç Málaga uña| LANG=C iconv --verbose -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
```

Output is:

```
abc ss ? EUR ??? M?laga u?a
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I stumbled upon the solution here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

As rodrigo said, I'd missed out

std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.UTF-8");